# Возможно ли передать NULL при UPDATE TABLE?

Tags: php, html, jquery

У меня есть форма, которая при отсутствии значения переменной сессии вносит данные в таблицу, а иначе редкатирует соответствующую строку. Проблема в том, что при редактировании если я хочу установить поле пустым оно просто игнорируется, а не становится NULL. Как мне это реализовать?

Оработчик php:

```
<?php
session_start();
require_once '../mysql_connect.php';

$title =  trim(filter_var($_POST['title'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING));
$description =trim(filter_var($_POST['description'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING));
$price =filter_var($_POST['price'], FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_FLOAT);

$price = ($price == '' ? NULL : filter_var($_POST['price'], FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_FLOAT));

$error = '';
if(strlen($title) <= 3)
    $error = 'Введите название'; 
else if (strlen($description) <= 5)
    $error = 'Введите описание';

if($error != ''){
    echo $error;
    exit();
}

if(isset($_SESSION["ProjectID"])){
    $sql = "UPDATE `project` 
            SET `title` = '".$title."', `description` = '".$description."', `price` = '".$price."' 
            WHERE `ProjectID` = '" . $_SESSION['ProjectID'] . "'";
    $query = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    $query->execute();
}else{
    $sql = 'INSERT INTO project(title, description, date, author, price) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)';
    $query = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    $query->execute([$title, $description, time(), $_COOKIE['login'], $price]);
    $_SESSION["ProjectID"] = $pdo -> lastInsertId();
}

echo 'Готово';
```

?>

Comment: пробел допиши..

Comment: Что добавится в запрос если строка `null`? Ничего. Пишите `$price == '' ? 'NULL'`

Comment: @AndreyMihalev, нет и еще раз нет, `'NULL'` или пустота, будет именно строкой, а не значением `NULL` - которое говорит, что нет значения. Можете сами проверить `VALUES(NULL)` и `VALUES('NULL')` 2 разные вещи.

Comment: Price числовой, но nullable. Когда я на phpmyadmin выполняю запрос "UPDATE `project` SET `price` = NULL WHERE `project`.`ProjectID` = 15" он становится NULL'ом

Comment: Ну вы же строку передаете:  `price = '".$price."' ` Уберите одинарные кавычки!

Comment: @And, это правда, да. Убрав кавычки, нул всё равно не принимает

Comment: А вы уверены, что `var_dump($price);` именно `null` ? Стоит проверить. И да, советую за место `filter_var` использовать `filter_input` - это так на вскидку.

Comment: Зачем мне дамп проверять если я это сделал только SQL'ем? Это точно NULL

Comment: NULL в тексте запроса должен быть литералом. *Зачем мне дамп проверять если я это сделал только SQL'ем?* Зачем Вы вообще тогда спрашиваете, если игнорируете рекомендации отвечающих? *Это точно NULL* Это Вы из General Log увидели? или как?

Comment: Затем, что `$price==''` может быть неверным сравнением, так-как если вдруг вам приходит `0.0`, раз там `float`, то собственно `$_POST['price']='0.0';` и выражение `filter_var($_POST['price'], FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_FLOAT)` вернет вам `00` и тут то вы встаете на коленки `'00' == ''` равно `false`. Да и в прочем `'0'==''` тоже вернет `false`, это не удивительно, ведь это же не `0 == ''`, что даст нам `true`.

Comment: Всё ещё не понимаю. Подход вкорне неверный? Потому что в таблицу при изначальной записи null (или что это вообще?) вставляется